# Why Multipart/mixed java mail content is sent as attachment in outlook?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am sending multi part email which is having text/plain and text/html but when i am getting mail in my outlook html content is coming as attachment and text/plain is coming in the body. i want both in the body.

pom.xml configuration is this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and java code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", sSMTPServer);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
    Session session = null;

    session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);


    Multipart mainMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
    Multipart htmlAndTextMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");


    MimeBodyPart BodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    BodyPart.setText(Header);
    htmlAndTextMultipart.addBodyPart(BodyPart);


    MimeBodyPart BodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    BodyPart1.setContent(Body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    htmlAndTextMultipart.addBodyPart(BodyPart1);

    for (int i = 0; i < htmlAndTextMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
        mainMultipart.addBodyPart(htmlAndTextMultipart.getBodyPart(i));
    }
    msg.setContent(mainMultipart);

    InternetAddress[] from = InternetAddress.parse("appdev@abc.com");
    InternetAddress[] toList = InternetAddress.parse(to);
    msg.addFrom(from);
    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toList);
    msg.setSubject("Multipart_Testing");

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(sSMTPServer, 25, null,
            null);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, toList);
    System.out.println("Sent");
    transport.close();
}
```

problem is only with outlook that html content is not coming in the body

[mail snippet of gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoxAF.png)

and in outlook  all contents are not getting rendered like gmail instead coming as attachment
[mail snippet of outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKtaZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get to control how mailers display your message, and different mailers will display the same message differently.  Your best bet is to put all your content into a single html part, and stick to pretty basic html.

Oh, and JavaMail 1.4.2 is **very** old, you should [upgrade to the current version](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) if possible.

Comment: @Bill Thanks you are correct I can put all the contents in a single part we don't have control on mailer clients how does they display .